# How to set Property value in WIX

Tags: wix, wix3

Usually, we can set this value as a text, while what I need is a directory name, which means I need set `ProgramFilesFolder` to this value.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [Directory table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368295.aspx). Pay attention to Remarks section, especially to this sentence:

> Note that when the directories are
>   resolved during the CostFinalize
>   action, the keys in the Directory
>   table become properties set to
>   directory paths.

This means that after CostFinalize action you can address any directory defined in your Directory table the way you do for [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370889.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I was still confused, I want to change the default installation path from parameter pass from outside. my code is <Property Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\COMPANY">
      <RegistrySearch Id="PreviousLocation" Key="Software\Microsoft\MyDemo" Root="HKCU" Type="directory" Name="TargetDIR" />
    </Property> if the value of Property is a text, it works well. while I want to put "[ProgramFilesFolder]\COMPANY" into the Property value, it was just showing this string, what I need is actually the text "c:\Program Files\COMPANY", Any suggestion

Comment: You can't set a property value to another property value this way. You should author a custom action for this: <CustomAction Id="youraction" Property="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\COMPANY" />